# Abstracting over repeated application within Monad chains

Tags: haskell, monads, higher-order-functions

The [Haskell wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/Maybe) has an example that shows how to chain `lookup` commands when trying to find different pieces of connected information throughout a database, seen here:

```
getTaxOwed :: String       -- their name
       -> Maybe Double -- the amount of tax they owe
getTaxOwed name = 
  lookup name phonebook >>=
    (\number -> lookup number governmentDatabase) >>=
      (\registration -> lookup registration taxDatabase)
```

and rewritten in `do` notation:

```
getTaxOwed name = do
  number       <- lookup name phonebook
  registration <- lookup number governmentDatabase
  lookup registration taxDatabase
```

Now, anytime I see a function repeated more than once I immediately try to think of ways to abstract over its repeated application, but as I haven't used `Monads` much in practice yet, and as they seem to already be at a pretty high level of abstraction, I didn't know how to approach that in this case.

What are some ways, if any, a coder could abstract over the common pattern above, that is, a call to `lookup` in every line?

(an aside: is this an appropriate context for the phrase "abstract over"? I felt it captured my meaning, but I'm not sure, and I'd like to make sure I'm using terminology appropriately as a relatively new coder; I looked through other posts which clarified its use and meaning but I still can't figure it out for this particular example)

Comment: I seemed to be a bit over-intimidated with using `Monads`, as it appears that a simple recursive function using a list of tuples (pairing each lookup key with it's directory) might be the solution: `lookupALot ((k,d):(keys,directories)) = lookup k d >>= lookupALot keys directories`; if only I can figure out a base case; perhaps I should make the result a `Maybe`?

Comment: Or even perhaps something like: `lookupALot :: ([String], [[String, String]]) -> Maybe Double,
lookupALot tuples = foldr (>>=) (base_case?) tuples`. I seemed to forget that the original function used data that already was in the Maybe type. Oops.

Comment: in this case I think you should do the same `head` and `tail` does (i.e. if there is no reasonable base case - if you need an non-empty list - it might be ok to fail) - or you can go first `Maybe (Maybe a)` and finally flatten this too ;)

Comment: btw: you should put this into an answer - also note that you can do this with [foldM](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM, ...)

Comment: It may look like you're calling the same function three times, but I bet `lookup` has a different type on every line there. Which makes it a *little* bit like calling three different functions -- and also severely complicates attempts to abstract over which function is repeated to the point that it is almost surely not worth it.

Comment: Carsten, foldM might be the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Big thanks to Carsten for the link to [`foldM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM)! Credit to them for the insight of this answer.

So, if we use `foldM`, we can write a function that repeatedly performs a `lookup` chained through multiple directories that depend upon each previous result. If, thanks to the use of `monads`, at any point `lookup` cannot find the current `key` in a directory, it will terminate, and return `Nothing`:

```
lookupALot :: Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
lookupALot key directories = foldM lookup key directories
```

this has output of the form

```
  foldM f k1 [d1, d2, ..., dm] -- k == key, d == directory
  ==
  do
    k2 <- f k1 d1
    k3 <- f k2 d2
    ...
    f km dm
```

which is exactly the same structure as

```
  do
    number       <- lookup name phonebook
    registration <- lookup number governmentDatabase
    lookup registration taxDatabase
```

Hence, a more compact way of writing `getTaxOwed` would be:

```
getTaxOwed :: String -> Maybe Double
getTaxOwed name = foldM lookup name [phonebook, governmentDatabase, taxDatabase]
```

Which kinda blows me away! That line of code will find the phone-number associated with a person's `name`, then check the `governmentDatabase` with their number for their `registration`, and finally find their tax information from that `registration`. Note though, that this will only work for data in the form of `[(a,b)]`, as indicated by the type of `lookupALot`.